# proof that specific disjoint sets are recursively enumerable, but don't lie in a decidable set and its complement

Tags: computability, decidability

let's call a set $A \subseteq \mathbb{N}$ recursively enumerable if it's "partial characteristic function" $\tilde{\chi}_A$ is computable, whereby $\tilde{\chi}_A$ is defined as: $\tilde{\chi}_A$:= 1, if $x \in A$ and  $\tilde{\chi}_A$ is undefined otherwise.

Now for $i = 0,1$ let $P_i$ be the set of all programmes p that terminate for input p and have output i. It's clear that $P_0 \cap P_1 = \emptyset$.
I'd be glad if you  could help me with showing that the sets $P_0$ and $P_1$ are recursively enumerable, but that there's no decidable set E with $P_0 \subseteq E$, $P_1 \subseteq \mathbb{N}\backslash E$.

Looking forward to your suggestions!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The partial characteristic function of $P_0$ is computable by the algorithm: "On input $p$, run program $p$ with input $p$; if and when it terminates with output $0$, print $1$."  $P_1$ is recursively enumerable similarly.

If they were separated by a decidable set $E$ as in the question, let $p$ be a program that outputs $1$ when $p\in E$ and outputs $0$ when $p\notin E$, i.e., $p$ computes the characteristic function of $E$. What would $p$ do when fed input $p$? It must eventually halt and output $0$ or $1$, since that's all $p$ ever does on any input. If it outputs $0$, then that means $p\in P_0\subseteq E$, so, by our choice of $p$, it should, on input $p$, compute $1$. Similarly, if $p$ on input $p$ outputs $1$, then $p\in P_1$, so $p\notin E$, and $p$ on input $p$ should output $0$. So we have a contradiction in either case. Therefore, no such program $p$ can exist.

Comment: Oh, I understand, it's so much easier than I thought! Thank you very much for the good explanation!

Comment: "if and when it terminates with output 0, print 1". - You meant "print 0", right?

and "therefore, no such program p can exist" implies that therefore such a decidable set E can't exist either?

Comment: @Studentu No, I meant what I wrote. If and when the computation of program $p$ on input $p$ terminates with output $0$, this shows that $p\in P_0$, and therefore the partial characteristic function of $P_0$ (as in the first paragraph of the question)is defined at $p$ and has value $1$ (not $0$) there.

Comment: Yeah, this part I understood. This is the contradiction we want. 
But for simply considering a program $P_0$ in the beginning, you wrote 

The partial characteristic function of $P_0$
is computable by the algorithm: "On input p, run program p with input p; if and when it terminates with output 0, print 1."  

So why "print 1"? Did you just write this to emphasize that the partial characteristic function has output 1 and therefore $P_0$ is recursively enumerable?

Comment: @Studentu To prove that $P_0$ is recursively enumerable, using the definition in the first paragraph of the question, I must give a program that computes the partial characteristic function of $P_0$. That partial characteristic function has (still quoting the definition) value $1$, not $0$, wherever it is defined. So a program that computes it had better print $1$'s not $0$'s.

Comment: Okay, I see, thank you Andreas!